# Converting an array of numpy arrays to DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy object that contains the following:

```
17506    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17507    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17508    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17509    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17510    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17511    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17512    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17513    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17514    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17515    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17516    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17517    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17518    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
17519    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

(An array that contains arrays of dtype('int32'))
How can I efficiently convert this to data frame in pandas and concantenate it (vertically) to an existing dataframe?

Comment: Is it array of arrays? What is your first column here?

Comment: Yes, It is array of arrays

Comment: if I simply do this: pd.DataFrame(arr) the result is that each row of the dataframe contains an array. But I want the nested arrays splitted into columns

Answer (score 4):

What seems to be the problem? You may need to further describe your data.

```
a = np.array([np.zeros(6) for _ in range(3)])

>>> pd.DataFrame(a)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
```